# Finding the parents of Caroline Hipp in Bruckinthal Germany

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, germany, vital-records

I have been looking for parents of Caroline Hipp Bommersbach for years and cannot find a clue as to who they were.

Their daughter Carol was born 28 June 1883 in Bruckinthal,Germany. She was married 7 July 1901 to a Martin Bommersbach and died in the state of North Dakota, USA in 1959.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  If you have any details of Caroline's immigration and/or naturalization would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to add them, or say that you have not been able to, please?  Also, can you clarify if her marriage was in North Dakota and where?

Comment: I notice you have Austria in your title but Germany in your question body and tags - can you clarify whether Austria is involved?

Comment: @PolyGeo Bruckenthal in Galicia was a German colony formerly in Austria-Hungary, at one point part of Poland, and currently in Ukraine

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  Could you add to your original question (by means of the edit link underneath the tags) a note about the sources of the information in your question?  It allows other users to see what records you have already found, and gives a baseline for further suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Hankinson News, October 15, 1959](http://www.mocavo.com/Hankinson-News-Marriage-and-Death-Announcement-Extractions-From-the-Hankinson-News-Hankinson-Richland-County-North-Dakota-1957-1959-Volume-2/313818/151):

> "K. BOMMERSBACH,
>   Funeral services were held on Saturday morning at
>   10 AM., from St. Philips Church at Hankinson for Mrs. Martin
>   (Karoline) Bommersbach, **daughter of the late Anton and Margaret Hipp**,
>   who passed away Wednesday morning after a lingering illness. Father
>   Lambert Studzinski celebrated the funeral mass.
>   Karoline Hipp-Bommersbach, was born June .., 1883, at Bruckinthal, Germany.
>   She was married to Martin Bommersbach in Austria on July 7th, 1901. They came to America in 1903, settling at Hankinson where has since
>   resided. To this union 13 children were born....seven sons and six
>   daughters.
>   She is survived by her husband, Martin and sons, John,
>   Frank, Anton and Joe of Hankinson; Ralph of Moorhead and Adam of
>   Fargo; Anna (Mrs. Howard Miche), Betty (Mrs. Amos Meland) and Rosalie
>   (Mrs. Charles Dorner), all of Chicago; Catherine (Mrs. Ben Herding),
>   Wehpeton, Three children preceded her in death....Mrs. Carl Rettig,
>   Margaret and Peter. **Also surviving is one brother, Mike Hipp, Cayuga, a brother Nick in Germany and Katherine Arnold, also Germany**. There are 32 grandchildren and 12 great-grandchildren.
>   Six grandsons were pallbearers: Paul and Donald Herding, Joe Rettig, David, Allen and Roger Bommersbach."

[FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org) is always a good place to start. While I cannot see a birth record specifically for Caroline, a brief search shows there are a few interesting records for possible siblings of Caroline. For example, a [Joseph Hipp](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:24SN-S7C), son of Anton Hipp and Margaretha Werner was married in New York in 1885. [Fritz Hipp](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:2W6X-6L6), son of Anton and Margaretha, died in Manhattan in 1895. The obituary provides other possible leads and sources to pursue to find Caroline's siblings, which may make it easier to trace her family in Europe.

Keep in mind that facts in obituaries are not always correct, so they must be verified using other sources.

As my comment suggests, Bruckenthal has changed 'nationalities' over the years. It was originally a German colony (hence the reason Caroline considered herself German), but it was in Galacia in Austria-Hungary. Between the First and Second World Wars, Bruckenthal was considered to be part of Poland. Currently it is in Ukraine. This makes it more difficult to track down records because you may have to search records in different countries or languages.